# Difference between Bioscience and Lifescience

Tags: terminology

Are bioscience and lifescience the same things? I am a little bit confused about it. If not, then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: they're pretty much the same thing in my mind - _bio_ means "life" and _biology_ is the study of life.

Comment: I agree with @MattDMo, they're the same thing.

Comment: I agree with everyone. Also, you originally tagged this question bioinformatics - *that* is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments and largely see them as the same thing, and many dictionaries would probably agree with this. However, in practical use (from my experience) **Life science** is used somewhat more broadly (everything from ecology and agricultural science to genomics and biochemisty), while **Bioscience** is more often applied to "whiter" lab-based biology and more technical applications (biotechnology, genetics, etc.). Personally, I would feel comfortable to label my research as *life science* but a bit more uneasy with *bioscience*. However, the terms are so vague that I wouldn't pass judgement on the content of research just based on these labels.

Comment: Whiter? What do you mean by whiter?

Comment: Lab coat (white) vs. field clothes (green), not caucasian ;).

Comment: hah. I've only seen one person wearing a lab coat lately, and it was an undergrad. No one here does field work, either. :P

Comment: @dd3 Wearing a lab coat in a lab is a sensible, if minimal, way of protecting your clothes and body against chemicals, radioactivity and biological agents. Not wearing one is neither clever, professional, nor, in some countries, legal. Certainly in my University students are not allowed into teaching laboratories without one. The same probably applies to research laboratories under British Health and Safety regulations. Your comment does you no credit.